# When did the word "brass" come to mean "officer", especially higher-ranked officers?

Tags: history, military

The word "brass" became synonymous to "officers", "senior officers" or "command" [due to their brass rank badges](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48029/what-does-the-brass-mean-exactly-in-military-context). I'm curious when was the first *recorded* usage of "brass" in this meaning.

Comment: Brass: ***Slang sense of "high officials" is first recorded 1899***, from their insignia. http://www.etymonline.com/word/brass

Comment: The insignias in question were the ones on their hats, thus brass hat and brass-hatted mean the same thing and the first recorded use of these are from 1887 and 1858, according to the OED

Answer (score 1):

The OED has a example from 1870:

*1870   Beloit College Monthly Oct. 12   At every big plantation or negro shanty yard Just to save his property the generals plase a gard The sentrys instruction to let no private pass, The rich mans house and table are fixed to suit the **brass**.*